# OpenCV detect hand and comparison images

Tags: android, c++, opencv

Purpose of my application is to take a photo hand (gesture) and comparing it with a picture that is in the database. The first option I was use is background subtraction on images:

http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/doc/tutorials/video/background_subtraction/background_subtraction.html.

The solution works, but sometimes, depending on the first picture is not properly cut hand.

The second option is to detect skin color: http://bytefish.de/blog/opencv/skin_color_thresholding/

Or is it better to use a hand detection based on xml files? To compare the images I wanted to use this method:http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/imgproc/histograms/histogram_comparison/histogram_comparison.html

Let me remind you that I'm talking about comparing the images to which they are gestures. I also read about the possibility of making the histogram is not the entire image only on the subject of the photo and then the data is more reliable, but do not know how to do it.

I want to compare the gesture as a single image, I do not mean here with the sequences. 1 picture for comparison with the baseline. Gesture detection is to enable someone eg. Will ring, and now I will have for example. 5 seconds to take pictures and compare them with the base because I'm not certain if appeared in the lens of the hand or not. Unless there is another solution.

Ultimately, it is to be a comparison of two images in which there will be some hand gestures.

Comment: Using Haar cascade detection for hand is better option because you don't have to depend on first image for background subtraction and  skin detection may fail in many cases.

Comment: Yes, but this option requires a rewrite of a large number of photos, and I need at the time the photo was taken to detect whether it is the hand or not. I tried to use it anymore. For the fist worked, but for no longer open hand or the hand lapped with 2 fingers. Thanks for the feedback!

Comment: @Rahulgalgali What do you think about my answer?

Comment: Actually I am stuck at same point,I have tried many XML which provides fist detection effectively but when it come to hand detection(Open Hand) it fails.I even tried to train Cascade using haar training but still the results are unsatisfactory.

Comment: @Rahulgalgali What do you think then? Which solution to use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your goal is to perform gesture recognition, you should take into account that gestures are sequence of images. 
Thus, if you want to compare gesture you'll have to find a "smart" way to compare the whole sequences, and not single images, because one frame can belong to different gestures.

State of the art approaches for gesture recognition involves the extraction of the Optical Flow between two consecutive frames and then compute the histogram of optical flow (HOF). Having computed the histograms for all the frame pair in the video sequence, you can use different strategies to compare gestures:

- You can concatenate all the HOF in the sequence and then perform **histogram intersection** to compare the two sequences
- You can use the **Bag of Word paradigm** to create a representation of the HOF

Here there are some pointers to this strateies:

- [Optical Flow](http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/doc/py_tutorials/py_video/py_lucas_kanade/py_lucas_kanade.html)
- You can check this article for extracting HOF: "Histograms of Oriented Optical Flow and Binet-Cauchy Kernels on
  Nonlinear Dynamical Systems for the Recognition of Human Actions"[Bag of words]
- [Bag of Words](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/features2d/doc/object_categorization.html)

However, if your application requires just the comparison between two images, I would suggest to extract the Histogram of Gradient (HOG) for each image and then compare them with the **histogram intersection** measure or, again, use the Bag of words paradigm (it is better if you're looking for higher level representations of the images). The HOG are provided within the OpenCv libraries [link](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/gpu/doc/object_detection.html)

Comment: I want to compare the gesture as a single image, I do not mean here with the sequences. 1 picture for comparison with the baseline. Gesture detection is to enable someone eg. Will ring, and now I will have for example. 5 seconds to take pictures and compare them with the base because I'm not certain if appeared in the lens of the hand or not. Unless there is another solution.

Comment: OK then I would suggest the HOG approach I was mentioning in the answer, it is a state of the art approach for image comparison. Another possibility is using the Bag-of-word. Of course training a classifier with HOG would result in even better performances, Support Vector Machine usually achieves good performance. OpenCV offers an implementation of SVM

Comment: Why HOG? HOG is used to detect objects. Ok, this may help to detect the hand, that's what you mean? What the comparison images?

Comment: @lukassz HOG is used not only to detect objects. Your task is to see if the hand in the current image corresponds to another image in your database, am I right? Then, extract HOG from both the current image and the ones that you have in you database (all of them, you can do it once at the beginning), then compare the HOG of the current image with the ones of the images in the databse and pick up the one with highest similarity. To compare 2 HOG histogram you can use histogram intersection (just google it to find its definition).

Comment: Yes, my intention is to check whether the image from the image corresponds to an image from the database. It should be also taken into account a mistake, because the gestures will never be done perfectly. This is work for any photo. The user takes a picture, the image is added to the database, and then the camera catches the image, the user shows the gesture and it is adjusted. Whether for a new photo in the database HOG work, or I'll have to learn it all again? Not sure if I understood your answer.

Comment: One more thing. HOG has detected my hand? At first I thought to take a series of pictures and then how come naktórymś comparison is a program that returns the appropriate value.

Comment: @lukassz You should use the nearest neighbor paradigm. You check which image in the db is similar to the current one (using HOG comparison) and then you select the gesture category that includes that image in the database. Then, based on this result, you can add the current image to that category in the db to increase the number of sample and make the system more robust. So you do not have to learn again. Alternatively you can learn an SVM classifier. In this case it will be more robust as more training samples are given.

Comment: Still to drive not yet understand. There are there any guides to this method?

Comment: @lukassz Regarding concepts you can just google SVM or Nearest Neighbor or HOG and you'll find many pointers to understand them. If you want some libraries,OpenCv has the methods to extract HOG from an Image. for SVM you can check [libsvm](http://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~cjlin/libsvm/), while nearest neighbor is very simple to implement, you just have to check which sample in the database with respect to the current one. You can also look for scientific articles where they describe the full hand recongition pipeline.

Comment: Ok, I read about it for now. What do you think about the method SURF?

Comment: SURF is useful to compute descriptors for interest point in images. You can use it in the place of HOG to train a SVM or a NearestNeighbor classifier. However, usually for gesture recognition it is more common to use HOG